# Format a float value to get the digits before a decimal point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, floating-point, number-formatting

In my application I have a music player, which plays music with a length of 0:30 seconds.

However in a UILabel I am currently displaying the progress, and as it is a float, the label is displaying i.e 14.765.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how I could get the label to display

0:14 rather than 14.765.

Also, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how I could display 0:04 if the progress was 4seconds in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works properly:

```
float time = 14.765;

int mins = time/60;
int secs = time-(mins*60);

NSString * display = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d",mins,secs];
```

Results:

```
 14.765 => 0:14
 30.000 => 0:30
 59.765 => 0:59
105.999 => 1:45
```

**EDIT**

In addition the 'one liner':

```
float time = 14.765;
NSString * display = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d",(int)time/60,(int)time%60];
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to convert your `float` to an integer, rounding as you wish. You can then use the integer division, `/`, and remainder, `%` operations to extract minutes and seconds and produce a string:

```
float elapsedTime = 14.765;
int wholeSeconds = round(elapsedTime); // or ceil (round up) or floor (round down/truncate)
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", wholeSeconds/60, wholeSeconds%60];
```

The `%02d` is the format specification for a 2-digits, zero padded, integer - look up `printf` in the docs for full details.

Answer (score 1):

```
//%60 remove the minutes and int removes the floatingpoints
int seconds = (int)(14.765)%60;
// calc minutes
int minutes = (int)(14.765/60);
// validate if seconds have 2 digits
NSString time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%02i",minutes,seconds];
```

that should work. Can't test it i'm on Win currently

Comment: why don't you use the zero padding for the format string: `"%i:%02i"`? It would eliminate the if statement.

Comment: % (remainder) is not valid on float operands, you must convert to an integer first

Comment: @Black Frog: didn't know that option, but great thanks!  
@CRD: thanks, that's right