# No zero before the decimal point or after second decimal

Tags: ios, xcode, zero, decimal-point

I have simple calculating in my app

```
-(IBAction)calculate {
    NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [nf setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
    [nf setMaximumFractionDigits: 2];

    float value1 = [[nf numberFromString: textField1.text] floatValue];
    float value2 = [[nf numberFromString: textField2.text] floatValue];

    float x = value1 * value2 / 100;
    label2.text = [nf stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: x]];

    [nf release];
}
```

Now, when I calculate result looks like this: `,75` or `64,5`

I need to my result looks like this: `0,75` or `64,50`

**My problem is there no zero before the decimal point or after second decimal**

Comment: Isn't this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668985/format-a-float-value-to-get-the-digits-before-a-decimal-point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you set your text in the UILabel, use

```
label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",x];
```

This will ensure you get 2 decimal places. You don't even need a number formatter.